# Insert values to table only if first Insert was successful

Tags: postgresql, insert, plpgsql, exception

Is there a way I could check the status of an insert query whether it was successful or not. I want to write to another table only if the first insertion was successful.

Below is the table I want to do the first insert and also it should return the conversation_id which I need for to make an insert to the second table.

Conversations table -

```
create table conversations (
  id uuid not null,
  conversation_id text UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY not null,
  participants jsonb not null,
  created_at timestamp with time zone,
  updated_at timestamp with time zone,
  avatar_url varchar(500),
  last_message varchar(32000)
)
```

After the successful insert on the first table, I should use the returned conversation_id and insert a record onto the messages table.After successful insertion it should return the value of the message field returned.

Messages Table -

```
create table messages (
  id uuid not null primary key,
  conversation_id text references conversations.conversation_id not null,
  message text,
  sender_id text,
  receiver_id text,
  message_type text,
  created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
)
```

And after the two inserts I need to make an update to the first table again with the returned value of the message field.

Here is the full function to do the above, the below function works when calling using select, but when I call it through my client I get this error

```
-- Could not find the public.new_conversation(members, the_conversationId) function in the schema cache

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_conversation(the_conversationId text, members jsonb, sent_message text)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
 conv_id text;
 the_message text;
BEGIN
   SELECT conversation_id into conv_id FROM conversations WHERE conversation_id = the_conversationId;
   if not found then
      insert into conversations(conversation_id, participants) values(the_conversationId,members) Returning conversation_id     into conv_id;
        if found then
            insert into messages(conversation_id,message) values(conv_id,sent_message) Returning message into the_message;
            if found THEN
            update conversations set last_message = the_message where conversation_id = conv_id;
            end if; 
        end if;
   end if;
   return conv_id;
END;
$function$
```

Should I be doing any exceptions handling for my insert statements?

Comment: This is commonly implemented using triggers.

Comment: Is there anyway we could do a check inside of a function?

Comment: What is "the first insertion"? I see only one

Comment: The insert you see there would be the first one, I want to know if I could get a status of that insert statement then do another insert.

Comment: The status of that insert is determined by Postgres not throwing an error, so, in the absence of [a handler](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING), if execution gets to the next statement it means the previous statement was successful.

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio. I read the documentation you linked, tried the exception handler like in the above code, i get this error - syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION"

Comment: The syntax error is because `EXCEPTION` goes at the same level as the `BEGIN`; you can't have it nested inside an `IF`/`END IF`. But you shouldn't have an exception handler for this situation anyway, as mustaccio noted: getting to the next statement is sufficient to know that the statement with `get_conversation()` succeeded.

Comment: Okay thanks @AdamKG

Comment: There are better solutions. But the best solution depends on a couple of key questions: 1. Can there be concurrent writes to the table? 2. Do you always insert the hard wired constants, or do you want to pass parameters? 3. Why the different data types for `conv_id` and `new_conv_id`? (Seems like both should be integer, as well as the return type.) 4. You mention writing to another table, but there is none in your code. Do you want to write the resulting ID from the first *SELECT or INSERT*? 5. Do you actually *need* a function? A single query with data-modifying CTEs might do the job.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter There wont be concurrent writes to the table. I will be passing in parameters from the client to this function. The conv_id is set as text as the value it will be receiving will be text. Sorry about the second insert statement not being there. I was thinking about how to implement it the best way. It will be 2 inserts and one update all happening in a sequence. The id from the first insert will be used in the second insert and after the second insert there will be an update happening to the first table.

Comment: The whole idea why I am doing this as a function is to reduce the number of API calls from my client. I believe if I do this using a function I just need to do one API call to the function instead of three which would be without a function. I am just a beginner in all of these, this is what I could come with. Please let me know if I am thinking in the right direction.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to add the important information you just posted in comments, that would make it a proper ("useful and clear") question. Plus, start with your exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE ...)`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have editted my post with all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **no concurrent writes on the involved tables**, this simpler function should cover everything you describe:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_conversation(INOUT _conv_id text, _members jsonb, _sent_message text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM conversations WHERE conversation_id = _conv_id) THEN
      INSERT INTO conversations (conversation_id, participants, last_message)
      VALUES (_conv_id, _members, _sent_message);

      INSERT INTO messages (conversation_id, message)
      VALUES (_conv_id, _sent_message);
   END IF;
END
$func$
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6263403469692aaa88c843528046f863)*

Most importantly, don't `INSERT` and later `UPDATE` the same row, when you can `INSERT` all at once.

I use an `INOUT` parameter, meaning the input for `_conv_id` will be the output, because I don't (need to) alter it anyway.

I don't see anything that would require `EXCEPTION` handling. If any exception occurs the whole function (which is *always* executed inside an outer transaction and hence atomic!) is rolled back.

The only remaining riddle is the role of the `id` columns. Since those are `NOT NULL`, you need to write to them unless they have a default.

Aside: `PRIMARY KEY` makes the column `UNIQUE NOT NULL` implicitly, this:

```
conversation_id text UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY not null,
```

should just be:

```
conversation_id text PRIMARY KEY,
```

If there can be concurrent writes, things are not as simple. See:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/939860)

Comment: Thanks Erwin for the detailed explanation.